# Command terminal

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal

using terminal windows, or cmd, powershell, there is a problem with the fact that I can not install using the script. that is: there is a 'php init' command after entering it, you must select one of two values. but the command line simply ignores all this and asks for an already new command. and she just stops that team.
how to deal with this?

Yes indeed. Data must be obtained in a new team. The php command should be open, but it should be completed. Here is an example of CMD work

```
C:\wamp64\www\yiip> php init 
Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0 
Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

[0] Development 
[1] Production 

Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] Quit initialization. 
PS C:\wamp64\www\yiip>
```

[Gif work CMD terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX8Bx.gif)

Comment: Are you saying you're having trouble setting up a new php project/app/environment (whatever you wanna call) using a script because php init wants user input?

Comment: @YuraLons, put the information from all three of your current comments, into your question itself, by using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62084804/edit) facility, please make sure that it is formatted appropriately. Then delete those comments, which will no longer be required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand but maybe php is not installed as a path variable?

Comment: path `PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0;C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\``

Comment: Looks like the init script has some kind of error and is not listening for input.i dont think its a command line problem
oh it is your script maybe show the script code then